# Save open PDF via excel

Tags: excel, pdf, adobe-reader, vba

I am trying to write a VBA script to save an open PDF via VBA. I have tried to use the script mentioned on the adobe adk but no variables are being declared is there a generic script to save a pdf file?

```
Set AcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")  
Set avdoc = AcroApp.GetActiveDoc  
If Not (avdoc Is Nothing) Then  
    Set PdDoc = avdoc.GetPDDoc  
    WasSaved = PdDoc.Save(PDSaveFull, "C:\")  
End If
```

Comment: Do you have `Acrobat Pro (or X)` installed?

Comment: Acrobat x (not pro)

Comment: *... to save an open PDF ...* and `Set avdoc = AcroApp.GetActiveDoc` do not work as you expect, I think. You'll need to find the exact PDF doc and reference that.

Comment: Do you get an error or something when you run this code?

Comment: The variable returns empty